# Clients polling service for activity

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, windows-services

I have a Windows service that continuously performs calculation tasks. There are multiple calculation steps performed as part of a single calculation task.

This service is required to log/track the calculation tasks and steps so that multiple clients can poll and observe the activity.

To meet this requirement, I've added a simple `Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>` (`_activity`) to my service that collects the activity messages. The key is a `Guid` representing the `CalculationTask.Id`, and the value is a `List<string>` holding the messages from the individual calculation steps.

I naively added a method to the service that is invoked by the clients (via wcf) to poll for activity messages. The client would pass in a `lastPolledTimeStamp` in an attempt to tell the service, "*give me all of your messages since I last polled*"...

```
private readonly Dictionary<Guid, List<string>> _activity = new Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>();
public List<string> GetActivity(DateTime lastPolledTimeStamp)
{
   var snapshot = _activity.ToList();

   return snapshot.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
      .Where(x => x.TimeStamp > lastPolledTimeStamp)
      .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
      .ToList();
}
```

Here are my problems and questions:

(1) When the client and service are on different machines, attempts to filter the results by date/time comparisons will not work. And I can't simply return everything in `_activity` each time `GetActivity` is called - there's too much data. There has to be some sort of filtering. What other options do I have?

(2) Another "problem" is knowing when an a key/value pair in the `_activity` dictionary can be removed. The clients are polling every 5 seconds. I want to keep the key/value pair around long enough so that clients have a chance to pick it up... Perhaps I should include another timer that executes to periodically clean up the old entries in `_activity`. Thoughts?

Comment: Why doesn't filtering by date/time work? Can you elaborate on the problem you are having with that? Is it simply that the clocks aren't in synch? If that's the case, couldn't you return the timestamp from the service along with the data and then the client could pass it back again on the next call.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You're correct. The date/time filtering doesn't work because the clocks aren't in sync. We've had cases where they are in different time-zones and no activity data was returned.

Comment: Returning the service's timestamp alongside the data would certainly work.

Comment: Re. cleaning out old data: is it more important that the data is cleaned out as quickly as possible, or that clients _never_ miss an update? Is there some way of knowing if a client has "logged off"? (Or indeed "logged on"?)

Comment: I'd say it's more important that clients get the messages. But it's not like the system will fail if a client misses one. At this tier, there's no way to know about the clients that are connected (logged on or off).

Comment: @JohnRussell: In that case, I'm still liking my suggestion. Just make sure to overestimate the required size since keeping a few out-of-date messages isn't gonna hurt you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, return the server's time with each response, and get the client to send this timestamp, rather than their own time, when making a request.

For the second problem: if the calculations/steps may be producing messages at different rates, rather than have a fixed-size buffer for each set of updates, I'd stick with running a cleanup job every so often, deleting messages older than [a small multiple of the client's ping interval].

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's exactly what I did to address each problem. For the second problem, I implemented a simple Timer that removed messages where the time stamp indicated that they were more than (for example) 15 seconds old.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem, I'd implement a circular array structure which will automatically overwrite old entries. If the rate that messages are written is constant, this should be easy. If it's variable, you'll have to figure out what size to make the array based on the expected maximum number of messages per 5 second period.

Comment: The rate at which the messages are written is very unpredictable and depends on data used in the calculations. I'd like to keep them in a dictionary if at all possible.

Comment: @JohnRussell: Well you could have a dictionary of circular arrays instead of a dictionary of lists, but the highly variable rate of messages is a problem. I could imagine writing an expander circular list that would check if the oldest entry is at least 5 seconds old before overwriting and if it's not just expand the list instead, but it might be more trouble that it's worth. You best bet might be a timer that fires periodically and trims your list as you original suggested.